# SVN tree conflict issue

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-merge

I am getting the tree conflict message as mentioned below -

```
514 (dev) dev:/export/home/user> svn status
 M      .
!     C ABC_NY
      >   local delete, incoming edit upon merge
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
```

What I did:

1. Created a feature branch from the trunk.
2. Did some changes in trunk; deleted few junk files from trunk.
3. Merged trunk to the feature branch. Everything was working fine till this point.
4. Did some changes in the feature branch; now the feature branch is ready for a release to PROD.
5. Tried merging the feature branch to trunk and having this conflict error.

Not sure why I am getting this error and how to avoid it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that a file/directory was edited on the branch that was deleted locally on the trunk.

So, check the following:

- Was `ABC_NY` modified on the branch since the last merge (or the creation of the branch) from trunk.
- Is `ABC_NY` still on the trunk?
- Was this directory/file removed or renamed on trunk?

You can always do a `svn resolved ABC_NY` to temporarily remove the conflict, and then handle it manually. However, I always recommend that you use the `--dry-run` parameter when you merge, and see where there might be possible conflicts, and then handle those conflicts before the actual merge takes place.